# How to know and remove multiple network adapters in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, network-adapter

How do I know and remove `multiple network adapters` in my *Network Connections* in Windows 10?

I have read *[How to delete Network Adapter for Windows 10](https://www.online-tech-tips.com/computer-tips/unable-delete-network-adapter-windows-10/)*.

But how do I know which ones to keep and which ones to uninstall?

[image: Multiple Network Connections]

[image: Device Manager]

Also, I have tried removing them, sometime back, but when the system restarts I can still see multiple Network Adapters in my Network Connections. So, is there a permanent fix for this?

Comment: Remove the disabled adapters.  Use the command prompt method.  You obviously have an malfunctioning application that is adding those TAP adapters

Comment: If your still confused Reset your network connection.

Comment: Thanks @Ramhound So you mean the command prompt method mentioned in the link. I will try it  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resetting my network connection didn't helped much.

**What worked out**

1. Check which network adapter is showing media as disconnected from command prompt (as [suggested by  Ramhound](https://superuser.com/questions/1302459/how-to-know-and-remove-multiple-network-adapters-in-windows-10#comment1934246_1302459))
2. And then, remove every TAP-WIN 32 Adapter Series manually from Device Manager.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon a similar problem, the solution to get the devices removed quicker was to run the RegEdit as TrustedInstaller and delete the entries on HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Enum\ROOT\NET. This isn't the best option, because you have to manually delete the entries, but it's way faster this way then using the Device Manager.